# Navigation Drawer in Android - OpenGLRenderer: Points are too far apart 4.000001

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

While i am clicking the items on Navigation drawer it shows me 
Message--OpenGLRenderer: Points are too far apart 4.000001.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your code that throws this error.

Answer (score -2):

Do not use vector drawable for icons, use PNG(.png) format images.